# NetBeans IDE for C++: "Resolve Missing Native Build Tools"

Tags: c++, windows, netbeans

I recently bought a laptop with Windows 8.1 on it and I'm having trouble using the NetBeans C++ IDE on it. When I build, this is the window that comes up:

[image]

And I'm assuming these are my options:

[image]

I've tried using C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe in the field with the red asterisk but that has done nothing for me.

All help appreciated.

Comment: This just in: Visual Studio Express is free! http://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs#d-express-windows-desktop

Answer (score 1):

I use C++ in Netbeans 8.0* using gcc, g++ in Cygwin. Cygwin was installed first, and then Netbeans C++.
Everything was done automatically for me.

You are missing the C++ compiler. It would probably help to fill in that line (see the red asterisk).
You would probably have
**C:\MINGW\bin\g++.exe**.